# Noob to PowerShell, copying files within folder

Tags: powershell, copy, compare, directory

Sorry if this is a really simple process.

I've got a folder structure with ~4,000 directories at root level (empty), and another location with another set of folders with data.

I want to copy only the files from within the folders in location2 to the folders within location1 ie \FolderABC123\Archive, but only if the directory names match. I'm sure windows explorer copy, or xcopy or some other utility can do it with more ease, but I'd like to get my head into PowerShell, and think this would be a good start?

thank you.
Chris

Comment: What have you done till now. Please elaborate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    # Fist, get a list of all target directories (i.e.: directories under $destination that have a match in $source)

    $targetDirs = dir -Path $source -Recurse -Force |
        ?{ $_.psIsContainer } |
        %{ $_.FullName -replace [regex]::Escape($source), $destination } |
        %{ if (Test-Path $_) { $_ }}

    # Then, enumerate all files from source and copy them only if the corresponding target dir exists

    dir -Path $source -Recurse -Force | 
        ?{ -not $_.psIsContainer } |
        ?{ Test-Path (Split-Path ($_.FullName -replace [regex]::Escape($source), $destination) -Parent) } |
        copy -Force -Destination { $_.FullName -replace [regex]::Escape($source), $destination }
```

Comment: thanks for the help guys, much appreciated. Will give it a go today.

Comment: David, thanks for your advice, I was able to get this to work!
To take this a step further, I have a subfolder in the destination folder, how can I select this as the folder to copy the items to? and how would I go about writing a log/csv file to record what was written to where, size etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can use powershell.
Set the path in the beginning.

```
$strSouce = "Path"
$strDestination = "Path"
```

Then search foreach file in the source.

```
Foreach ($objFile in Get-ChildItem -Path $strSouce -Recurse | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.PsIsCointainer -eq $false}) {]
```

Copy every item from the source to the destination. For the destination you have to replace the source path to the destiantion path.

```
Copy-Item -Path $objFile.FullName -Destination $objFile.FullName.Replace("$strSouce", "$strDestination")
```

For your learning, set the snippet to the correct place.

Comment: thanks heaps Patrick. I had trouble getting this code to work. Apart from a few typos I discovered, I still couldn't get it going. I eventually had it going through without error, but I couldn't get a copy to happen. The $objFile variable seemed to always be empty?