# PowerShell exporting results to csv while checking and processing array

Tags: powershell-2.0, export-to-csv

Thanks to @DavidBrabant for helping me with my first question, it helped me immensely.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25546642/3985581

Was hoping somebody could look at the code at the above link and advise how I could go about writing some information about the copy process to a csv file?

Thank you.
Chris

Comment: Please show what you have tried yourself. Stackoverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: Thanks chthonicdaemon, unfortunately at this stage, I don't have the scripting knowledge to be able to contribute much. I am learning this off my own back, first time using any form of scripting with no formal training. I'm trying.

the simple output cmdlets I understand and can get to work when dealing with simple code, but as explained, it's incorporating it into the code that @David Brabant helped me with.
Things like $Result=New-Object PSObject, $Result | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value "$User" I understand but not in context of code in my first question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help thus far guys, @DavidBrabant and @chthonicdaemon
It would have been helpful to get some ideas on how to dynamiclly capture the values as they are written, at this stage, I haven't worked this out. So I thought about it and just thought I would gather all the details AFTER the copy process.

I just used the conventional method of reading the copied directory structure using:
`Get-ChildItem -Path $destination -Recurse |`
foreach{ $var = $_.Parameter | Select-Object `@{n="column heading";e={$var} | Export-Csv $destination\Results.csv -NoTypeInformation` 
This gives me an output as follows..

#### FilePath            ____________________________Name_______Size_______Type

C:\folder script\test\aabd1612\QuotaSize.nsf____QuotaSize_____663552_____.nsf